# Unused friend class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend

Is there a way to detect (for instance with compiler warning) if classes are declared `friend` but do not access private members, ie. when friendship is useless?

Comment: Maybe you can stick together a program using the Clang libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler warnings are not standardised, so this depends on your specific compiler(s). I would be very surprised if any of them supported this, however. A similar situation would be if you had a public member function which was only called by other public members (meaning it needn't be public), and once again I don't think any compilers detect this.

Doing either of these tests would mean extra work for the compiler writers, and  I doubt if they would see them as sufficiently useful to implement.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your example of public members, but otherwise I agree with your answer.

Comment: @Helltone: I guess he means that if a public member function is accessed only through other functions of the same class, it need not be public at all.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how to detect this using compiler warnings but another way of doing this would be to go to your class definition file and do a search & replace for `friend class` with `/*friend*/ class` and see if it still compiles. Of course, this could get rather tedious for a large project.

Comment: That causes a rather complex change in semantics. It would be rather hard to explain in a comment here, but basically name lookup differs.

Comment: @MSalters: Do you have a link where I can go read about it at? I'm curious to know what the change in semantics is.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of. Maybe there's a refactoring tool out there that can do it. You can always try removing the friendship and see if it still compiles, but that might be time consuming for a large project.

Answer (score 0):

You could compile the code to see that it compiles, then remove all 'friend' declarations (perhaps programmatically with sed) and sees if it still compiles.

Comment: The following macro is an easy way to turn 'friend' (and the rest of that line of code) into a comment. This won't work if the friend declaration is multi-line.    #define friend //